# .Net Core 2 Signalr alpha2 Hub not working

Tags: .net, .net-core, signalr

I have a major issue I can not solve. I have a.net core 2 project with jwt auth and trying to get a basic signalr hub test to work. The connection from the client seems to work but the connection is promptly dropped with a 204 code.

My hub is running on another URL than my front end UI so CORS is involved.

**I removed real keys and my project name

this is what the client console outputs:

[image: console]

Here is my startup code:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        services.Configure<DiAssemblies>(Configuration.GetSection("DiAssemblies"));
        services.Configure<StripeSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe"));
        services.Configure<AzureStorageSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureStorageSettings"));

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                x => x.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });


        services.AddCors();

        services.AddIdentity<testApp.Identity.ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<testApp.Identity.Context>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;


        })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("authkeyasdfasdfasdfsadfasdfda")),
                    ValidIssuer = "https://testApp.com/",
                    ValidAudience = "https://testApp.com/",

                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {

                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Auth issue");
                        Debug.WriteLine(context.Exception);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Query["authToken"]))
                        {
                            context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", context.Request.Query["authToken"]);
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Auth issue");
                        Debug.WriteLine(context.Error);
                        Debug.WriteLine(context.ErrorDescription);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

        services.AddMemoryCache();

        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });

        services.AddSockets();
        services.AddSignalRCore();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register dependencies, populate the services from
        // the collection, and build the container. If you want
        // to dispose of the container at the end of the app,
        // be sure to keep a reference to it as a property or field.
        //builder.RegisterType<MyType>().As<IMyType>();
        builder.Populate(services);
        var diHelper = new DiHelper();
        var diAssemblies = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DiAssemblies:List");
        var assemblies = diHelper.GetAssemblies(diAssemblies.Split(',').ToList());
      //  Console.Write(diAssemblies);
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);

        ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

        //foreach(var assembly in assemblies)
        //    services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(assembly).AddControllersAsServices();

        // Create the IServiceProvider based on the container.
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(
            options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
        );


        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("chat");
        });
    }
}
```

My Hub (a break point on any of the methods never gets hit)

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public ChatHub()
        {
            var t = 0;
        }


        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).InvokeAsync("send", "connection made");

            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public Task Send(string message)
        { 
            return Clients.All.InvokeAsync("send", message); 
        }
    }
```

Client javascript:

```
<script>
      window.connection;
      window.connection = new signalR.HubConnection("https://localhost:44367/chat?authToken=" + 'bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.yyJzdWIiOiJhYzNkMTU3OC05YjU5LTRmNzQtOWMxYi01MWZlYjk2YmQ4YzEiLCJqdGkiOiJidnRlc3QxIiwiZXhwIjoxTYI2NjY1OTM3LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Jpc3ZpbmUuY29tLyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi1vYmlzdmluZS5jb20vIn0.GxycqmyVsdHkW3M5yRH7arGkR3K-jAE2zrPrgoJnh-M', 
                                { transport: signalR.TransportType.LongPolling });

      window.connection.on('send', function(message) {
        alert(message);
      });


      window.connection.start().then(function() {
        console.log("SignalR Connected: Chat");
        window.connection.invoke('send',"hi").then(function (chats) {
          console.log(chats);
        });
      }, function () {

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you remove the transport: signalR.TransportType.LongPolling

Comment: No signalr 2 requires you to set a transport

Comment: Signalr 2 or .net core 2.  Why are you using long polling by default instead of using web sockets?

Comment: testing on windows 7

Comment: Hmm lemme check my project for differences off the top of my head.  Where is your authentication middleware to intercept your get parameter and translate it to jwt?

Comment: I just checked my project I do not set a transport and everything works fine

Comment: take a look at my onmessagerecieved in the startup for the jwt stuff

Comment: What is this? Where do you authenticate your jwt I do not see any middleware to set the headers? Did you try removing transport, it’s not needed

Comment: Ok cool I see it now that looks cleaner than middleware

Comment: Let me know if removing the transport doesn’t work I’m instanciate mine without it and everything works fine, the only other difference I have is that my hubs take it a hubcontext so my server can use the hub to push to the client easier

Comment: i just checked and i was mistaken not setting sets it to websockets but i cant get websockets to work on windows 7 my last try it to switch to my windows 10 laptop but still if longpolling wont work thats not ideal.

Comment: I thought signalr works by default with web sockets but if that fails it automatically falls back to long polling?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had the same issue starting.  See my answer

Comment: the old signal r used to the new cor version doesn't fall back

Comment: are you saying your not using Signalr R for .Net Core your using Signalr 2 for .Net 4.5 on an .Net Core Application?

Comment: @See my current answer, your missing Allow Credentials, Your App Policy Ignores the policy you created in the server

Comment: I'm using signalr core. I was saying signalr core doesn't do auto fallback from what i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew this had to be something easy but hopefully if anyone else runs into this it'll help them too.

After pulling my hair out I took a step back and noticed the logs were showing the hub was found I noticed hidden a few lines up that another mvc controller was also being invoked. After finding the controller I noticed it did not have the attribute [Route("api/[controller]")].

Added that and boom everything started working! Seems that every controller needs to have at least a route set or else mvc will take the call before signalr has a chance to fully fire.